# How to apply a force to a sprite?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-physics

I'm working with a game where you juggle a ball and to keep the ball in the air you need to apply forces to the ball.

I'm thinking if you touch right under the ball (180 degrees) and the maximum radius the more power you will kick away with the ball. So for an example if you touch the ball at 160 degrees and radius 6 you will be given less power than if you hit the ball at 170 degrees and radius 8,5.

[image]

How should I tackle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by using several values:

Direction(int). on the right side direction is defined as 0, top 90,left 180,bottom 270; You can use it to describe an angle.

Force(double). a constant value to describe how much force is applied.

Point(int,int) to describe a point on your canvas.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

You can then add several useful calculations as:

int Distance(Point,Point): Math.hypot(x1-x2,y1-y2) [This is the source code giving the distance between two points]

The final movement can be done in several ways. I'd probably do it like this:

Per Tick:
Get current force. Add gravity force (9.81 in angle 270)

Per Click:

Take the position of the click and the position of the ball. 
Calculate distance.
Calculate angle (Trigonometrics)
Finally calculate the force and add it.

How to add force?

Take angle.
Take "power".
Use more trigonometrics to calculate this.

I hope this helped you a bit. Sry for the format

Comment: Oh i recommend using my way for direction/angle, as trigonometrics are easier then :))